# Maven war plugin copy resource actually copying the file instead of symLinks

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

In my web app folder, i have created symLinks for some of the files and folders. When I use mvn war:war plugin they are actually copying the files and folders instead of symlink.

I want symLinks should be copied instead of actual files and folders. Is there any way by which we can achieve the same.

Comment: How should symlinks work inside a WAR file?

Comment: There are some containers that can understand symlinks inside war file like JBOSS. Let me know if my assumptions are wrong. In the war file i have two folder 1 , folder2 I dont want my static resources like js html to be repeated across folders hence i want to use symlink approach here

Comment: The question is which version of war plugin do you use ? Furthermore why are you calling the goal instead via life cycle?

Comment: Why do you need them twice times? Isn't that showing there is an issue in the app ?

Comment: It's a legacy GWT project because of GWT inherit module structure they are getting duplicated. I am trying to optimize on this hence thought of using the symlinks. Btw Maven war plugin 3.0.0. results are the same when I invoke the goal or via the life cycle.

Comment: Please try most recent version of maven-war-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) Version 3.2.2 ..first...to be honest I never heard about symlinks inside a WAR/JAR file ever...

Comment: sure thanks will do the same. Here are some threads where you can see people have tried using symlink in war https://developer.jboss.org/thread/39021

Comment: 12 years ago? really? Maybe you can elaborate a little bit more what exactly you are doing? Maybe a different solution exists?

Comment: Hi, I have followed another approach now. I copied the common sources (Js/Html) into another folder under web app and created a soft link after the exploded war is created using shell script plugin.

Comment: Do you have a single war which is being created? Then I don't understand why you need symlinks? Can you explain more detail best would be an example of a such a project?...